# SQL запрос на повторяющиеся значения

Tags: sql

Из таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES выдать значения JOB_ID так, чтобы они могли повторяться, но только в разных департаментах. Сделать сортировку по столбцу JOB_ID в порядке от Z к A.
Попробовал сделать так, но не вышло:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department_id, job_id 
ORDER BY job_id DESC 
FROM hr.employees;
```

Как реализовать правильно?

Comment: Поменяйте порядок - select -> from -> order by

Comment: Почему то не сортирует от Z к A

Comment: Могу посоветовать тогда обернуть это в еще один select `select * from (SELECT DISTINCT department_id, job_id FROM hr.employees) order by 2 desc`

Comment: Спасибо! А что значит 2 desc, а конкретно цифра 2, номер поля?

Comment: Да, номер поля, это для ленивых )